# Can I use 0 as a signal parameter in pthread_kill

Tags: c, pthreads

I know that pthread_kill requires Signal as a parameter but I am just curious about that what will be happen if I will give 0 as a signal (no SIGUSR1 or any other) .

Thread will be still killed in above situation ?

I am trying to learn these stuffs I am putting my hands in threading in C.

Comment: Have you tried [reading a reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_kill.html)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a trivial RTFM question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will happen exactly what is described in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) :

> If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed.

That means it will act like pthread_kill has send the signal, but without sending it. It's usefull when you try to check wether a particular PID respond to signal or not. It's a "dry-run".

Edit : Well, out of habit I've writted "PID", but it's more the "TreadId" than any other things.

Comment: It means thread will not killed .. Am I right ?

Comment: How can your thread be killed if the signal is not sent ? And you can just test it, it's really simple to do.

Comment: Thnx again ... Doubt cleared :)